# 3D Touch not working

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

im trying to add 3dtouch item to my app icon. here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
     if shortcutItem.type == "com.eDidaar.eDidaar.addEvent"{
       let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let addEventVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addEvent") as! ADDEvent
        if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            navigationController.pushViewController(addEventVC, animated: true)
        }


}
```

but 3d touch doesn't appear when i launch the application
what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed my code to this and it worked fine:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    if shortcutItem.type == "com.eDidaar.addEvent" {
        let sb = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let addEventVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addEvent")
        let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        root?.present(addEventVC, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
            completionHandler(true)
    })
}
```

}